# Reusing messages in quickfix

Tags: quickfix

I am using quickfix C++ v1.14.3. In my application, I want to reuse a message object. So everytime I use it I call the clear() method on the object. However this clears the header and the msgType as well. Is there a way I can clear the body, reset the header by using reverseRoute method?